# Getting Error with result

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    success: function(response){
                        $('#ul').html("");
                    var obj = JSON.parse(response);


    public function autocomplete(){ 
             $search =  $this->input->post('search');
             $query = $this->get_apartments($search);
             echo json_encode ($query);

        }

        public function get_apartments($search)
          {

             $query = [
                'val'     =>'*',
                'table'   => 'tbl_apartments as apt',
                'where'   => [],
                'orderby' => 'apt.id',
                'orderas' => 'desc',
                'in_value'=> '',
                'like'    => ['likeon' => 'apt.apt_no', 'likeval' => $search]
             ];
             $datasss = [
                ['table' => 'coach as bd' , 'on' => "bd.bd_code = apt.bd_code", 'join_type'=>'inner']
             ];

            $result = $this->common->datasss_with_in($query,$multijoin);




    }
```

> When I am Using To print_r($result); exit; to see the result it
>   showing me the result but when i commented this line its showing me
>   that obj is null... why this happening

Comment: there is no `strpos` function in above code ....

Comment: i din't see any `strpos()` in your given code. it's  on Line Number: 2276. so you have to show the exact code

Comment: if (strpos($table, ',') !== FALSE)
  {
   return $this->_track_aliases(explode(',', $table));
  }

Comment: @Arushi  can you show us the output of `var_dump($table);` and please paste your code in your question not in comment

Comment: provide the `multijoin` method code here

Comment: I agree, I'd like to see the output of `var_dump($table)`

Comment: wait i am updating my complete code

Comment: this is the code where i am getting error when i am recieving the data

Comment: Might be the issue in this method `multijoin_with_in`, priovide this method too

Answer (score 0):

get_appartments() should return something:
`return $result;`

so $query will get a value.

check what you receive in javascript using

`console.log(response);`

```
success: function(response) {
   $('#ul').html('');
   for(var $i=0;$i<$response.rows.length;$i++) {
      $('#ul').append('<li>' + response.rows[$i].building_name + '<li>');
   }
}
```

Comment: when i did this that time var obj = JSON.parse(response); getting null

Comment: how about console.log() to see what is in response? Me, I never use JSON.parse(). Not sure what that will gain.

Comment: {"res":true,"rows":[{"id":"2","apt_no":"301","site_id":"11","bd_code":"S11_B2","core":"1","floor":"3"
,"building_name":"BT Tower","street_name":"3 Coombe Hill","town_city":"Swanage","postal_code":"BH19 3DP"
,"country":"UK","total_cores":"3","total_floors":"10","total_apartments":"60","total_plant_rooms":"25"
,"total_parking_space":"50","status":"1","added_date":"2017-06-23"}]}

Comment: so the value is in javascript. What do you need to do with these values?

Comment: after that i did  var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                if(obj.length>0){ but its going blank why

Comment: I added how I would fill a <ul> with data

Comment: {"res":true,"rows":[{"id":"2","apt_no":"301","site_id":"11","bd_code":"S11_B2","core":"1","floor":"3"
    ,"building_name":"BT Tower","street_name":"3 Coombe Hill","town_city":"Swanage","postal_code":"BH19 3DP"
    ,"country":"UK","total_cores":"3","total_floors":"10","total_apartments":"60","total_plant_rooms":"25"
    ,"total_parking_space":"50","status":"1","added_date":"2017-06-23"}]}

I want to remove     {"res":true,"rows": from the starting of the json data how can i remove that from the json data

Comment: why? either you only look to reponse.rows. And you still can send messages from ajax (error etc) or you change behaviour of multijoin_with_in(). I would just ignore data in other properties than .rows

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer i need to return $result['rows]; simple solution cos json not accepting complete inm y case